# How to resolve an error after deploy on heroku?

Tags: django, heroku

After deploy I have an error whenever I try to push a button.
What to do?

Text of error: ProgrammingError at /notion/
relation "base_notion" does not exist
LINE 1: ... "base_notion"."title", "base_notion"."body" FROM "base_noti...

Comment: It seems that you need to migrate your DB

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you are attempting to load data from your database without actually creating the tables / relationship(s).

If you are using a database ORM or connector that manages migrations - such as Django or sqlalchemy - then you may need to create a new a new migration file, which is a library specific operation.

Once created, you can implement a [Release Phase](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase) task which will apply those migrations once a Heroku deploy finishes. This reduces the time between your code & database being "out of sync" with each other and hopefully avoids this issue from occurring in the future.